# Merging The same specific json object in two different json arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to merge the same specific json object on two different json arrays dependent on an json data ID.

JSON Data Set 1

```
{
    "Product":[
                {
                "product_id": "123",
                "location_id": "222",
                "product_code": "abc",
                },
                {
                "product_id": "456",
                "location_id": "111",
                "product_code": "xyz",
                }
            ]
}
```

JSON Data set 2

```
{
    "Location":[

            {
                "location_id": 111,
                "location_name": "alpha"
            },
            {
                "location_id": 222,
                "location_name": "tango"
            }


        ]
}
```

The Results would be something like this

```
{
    "Product":[

                {
                    "product_id": "456",
                    "location_id": "111",
                    "product_code": "xyz",
                    "location_name": "alpha"
                },
                {
                    "product_id": "123",
                    "location_id": "222",
                    "product_code": "abc",
                    "location_name": "tango"
                }
            ]
}
```

So far this is the code I've done.

```
var finalJson = {};

                    _.each(_.keys(productArray,locationArray), function(key) {
                        finalJson[key] = _.flatten(_.zip(productArray[key], locationArray[key]));
                    });

                    console.log(finalJson);
```

Comment: sorry updated the code

Comment: Yes, the merge result should be based on the same location ID.

Comment: right, so `var result = {Product: locationArray.map((location, index) => Object.assign(location, productArray.find(product => String(product.location_id) == String(location.location_id))))};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple algorithm could be using nested loops to go through both arrays, like this:

```js
let allProducts = [{
    "product_id": "123",
    "location_id": "222",
    "product_code": "abc",
  },
  {
    "product_id": "456",
    "location_id": "111",
    "product_code": "xyz",
  }
];


let allLocations = [

  {
    "location_id": 111,
    "location_name": "alpha"
  },
  {
    "location_id": 222,
    "location_name": "tango"
  }
];

let result = allProducts.map((product) => {
  let matchingLocation = allLocations.find((location) => {
    return location.location_id == product.location_id;
  });
  return Object.assign(product, matchingLocation);
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks this work well. Liked the simplicity of the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a hashmap of the locations using location id as keys, then iterate the Product array

```js
let arr1 = {
  "Product": [{
    "product_id": "123",
    "location_id": "222",
    "product_code": "abc",
  }, {
    "product_id": "456",
    "location_id": "111",
    "product_code": "xyz",
  }]
}

let arr2 = {
  "Location": [
    {
      "location_id": 111,
      "location_name": "alpha"
    }, {
      "location_id": 222,
      "location_name": "tango"
    }
  ]
}
let locIds= _.keyBy(arr2.Location, 'location_id');
_.each(arr1.Product, (o) => _.assign(o, locIds[o.location_id]));

console.log(arr1.Product)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```